# Three.js How to use quaternion to rotate camera

Tags: javascript, three.js

In Three.js, I would like to use THREE.quaternion to make the camera object rotate to the selected object.

I did search the web but found no example/demo or document about how to use this quaternion class.

I try my luck with following code:

```
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 40, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000 );
    camera.position.y = 10;
    camera.position.z = 0;
    camera.position.x = radious;
    camera.useQuaternion = true;

   // I did use the TrackballTrackballControls. Maybe it causes the problem so I put it here
    controls = new THREE.TrackballControls( camera, document.getElementById(_canvasElement) );

    // function to make the camera rotate to the object
    function focusOn3DObject(obj){  
        obj.useQuaternion = true;
        obj.quaternion = new THREE.Quaternion(obj.position.x, obj.position.y, obj.position.z, 1);

        var newQuaternion = new THREE.Quaternion();
        THREE.Quaternion.slerp(camera.quaternion, obj.quaternion, newQuaternion, 0.07);
        camera.quaternion = newQuaternion;
    }
```

But it doesn't work. Did I miss something?
Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that in newer THREE.js builds, `useQuaternion` has been removed. The library now uses quaternions by default.

Comment: Also note that today (Aug/2015) THREE's Camera objects have a method  .lookAt(vector3) - it receives a Vector3 with the position of an object to look at. You can pass any object3d.position as parameter, for the camera to look at it. Check it out: http://threejs.org/docs/index.html#Reference/Cameras/Camera

Answer (score 18):

Slerp is quite easy. It takes 4 parameters:

- `targetRotation` the actual camera rotation
- `destinationRotation` the object rotation
- `destinationRotation` new quaternion which will be the new camera rotation
- `percentOfRotation` this parameter is playground, I'm using 0.07 here right now, could be value between 0 (0%) and 1 (100%)

This is my rotation method:

```
var qm = new THREE.Quaternion();
THREE.Quaternion.slerp(camera.quaternion, destRotation, qm, 0.07);
camera.quaternion = qm;
camera.quaternion.normalize();
```

Hopefully this will help you. And don't bother I also worked some weeks on the perfect camera following.

Comment: Hi, in documentation, .slerp has only 2 parameters... https://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Math/Quaternion...Did I misunderstood something ?

Comment: @SébastienGarcia-Roméo there are two slerp methods on Quaternion -- the one used in this answer is the static one. Both are listed on the [quaternion docs page](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/math/Quaternion.slerp), but the static method is at the bottom.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the method applyQuaternion from ThreeJs

```
 const quaternion = new THREE.Quaternion(obj.position.x, obj.position.y, obj.position.z, 1);

 camera.applyQuaternion(quaternion); // Apply Quaternion

 camera.quaternion.normalize();  // Normalize Quaternion
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this line wont work:

```
obj.quaternion = new THREE.Quaternion(obj.position.x, obj.position.y, obj.position.z, 1);
```

You need to set

```
obj.useQuaternion = true
```

After adding object to scene, when you rotate it will be automatically applied to `obj.quaternion`.

The second point is you should apply the object to your controls and not the camera. Because you want to control the object and not the camera?

Comment: I would like to make the camera rotate and focus on the object. The camera would move around the object. So I think that the camera will be in controlled. Were I wrong?

Comment: It look like I'm finding in the dark as there is no document or a example about this :(. Could you please explain me the function slerp? What're the parameter for? I tried your suggestion but not succeed.

Comment: Note that in newer THREE.js builds, `useQuaternion` has been removed. The library now uses quaternions by default.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I've done it :

1. Get the current quaternion of your camera (initialQuaternion)
2. Create a clone of your camera
3. Make the clone look at the target using the lookAt method
4. The thing is, the lookAt method of the camera will actually make it look AWAY from the target, so you have two options :

- Either use the lookAt method directly, then invert the rotation
- Or compute the position the target should have so that when looking away from it, you actually look in the correct direction

6. Get the new quaternion of the clone (targetQuaternion)
7. By using an animation loop, do a slerp between the initialQuaternion and the targetQuaternion

Answer (score 0):

I have tried using it:

```
    var newQuaternion = new THREE.Quaternion();
        THREE.Quaternion.slerp(camera.quaternion, obj.quaternion, newQuaternion, 0.01);
        camera.quaternion = newQuaternion;
        camera.quaternion.normalize();
        camera.matrixAutoUpdate();
```

However, I have failed to get the desired outcome. I know it is a fairly old post but I would be happy if someone could respond. I didn't see any other relevant posts other than this so really hoping for someone to respond.

Here is my problem in detail: [Rotate camera to look at Selected object in three.js](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58740616/12198192)