# Rotating 3D Object in Three.js

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js, quaternions

Using Three.js I have a simple scene set up with a cube. I would just like to learn how to rotate the object using Quaternion. Any suggestions of how to learn how to do this?

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11665562/three-js-how-to-use-quaternion-to-rotate-camera

Comment: I dont want the camera to rotate, I want the object itself to

Comment: Show what you have tried, preferably with a live example, and ask a specific question.